# react-native-fs: How to add code in MainApplication

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, react-native-fs

I'm adding `react-native-fs` to my React Native project, and in the section `For react-native 0.29.0 and higher` in the [documentation](https://github.com/itinance/react-native-fs) it says to add the following code:

```
import com.rnfs.RNFSPackage; // <------- add package

public class MainApplication extends Application implements ReactApplication {
   // ...
    @Override
    protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
      return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
        new MainReactPackage(), // <---- add comma
        new RNFSPackage() // <---------- add package
      );
    }
```

Currently my code in this section looks like this:

```
@Override
protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
  @SuppressWarnings("UnnecessaryLocalVariable")
  List<ReactPackage> packages = new PackageList(this).getPackages();
  // Packages that cannot be autolinked yet can be added manually here, for example:
  // packages.add(new MyReactNativePackage());
  return packages;
}
```

If I replace my existing code with the suggested code, it gives me the following two errors:

```
ion.java:27: error: cannot find symbol
            new MainReactPackage(), // <---- add comma
                ^
  symbol: class MainReactPackage
```

and

```
ion.java:26: error: cannot find symbol
          return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
                 ^
  symbol: variable Arrays
```

How should I approach this?

Comment: Which version are you using of RN? If you are using RN 0.60.0+ the link is automatically done on Android, so no need to manually link a native library like this. reference: https://reactnative.dev/blog/2019/07/03/version-60#native-modules-are-now-autolinked

Answer (score 0):

As the comment mentions auto-linking should take care of linking part on react-native >= 0.60. If you need to add the package manually simply uncomment this line `packages.add(new MyReactNativePackage());` and replace `MyReactNativePackage` with `RNFSPackage`.

So your code will look something like this

```
import com.rnfs.RNFSPackage;

...
@Override
protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
  @SuppressWarnings("UnnecessaryLocalVariable")
  List<ReactPackage> packages = new PackageList(this).getPackages();
  // Packages that cannot be autolinked yet can be added manually here, for example:
  packages.add(new RNFSPackage());
  return packages;
}
```